# Cómo aumentar la velicidad de carga DATATABLE

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

solicitando su ayuda para aumentar la velocidad de carga de las DataTables. Genero las tablas de manera dinámica a través de una consulta a la base de datos y del lado del cliente les doy formato con javascript. Funciona de maravilla y una buena manera de mostrar la información, el problema se genera cuando probé con una consulta de 15,000 registros y tarda al rededor de 3 minutos para la carga.

Las tablas las genero de la siguiente manera:

```
Function fnDTCALIFICADORAS()
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM VCALIFICADORAS";
        $CONEXION = fnConexion();
        $RESULTADO = mysqli_query($CONEXION,$SQL);
        $TABLE = "<table id='dtCalificadoras' class='table table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<thead>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; display: none;'>ID</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem;'>Calificadora</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem;'>Calificación</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem;'>Acciones</th>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</thead>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tbody>\n";
        while($REGISTROS = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULTADO))
        {
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style='font-size:1.1rem; display: none;'>".$REGISTROS["ID"]."</td>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style='font-size:1.1rem; vertical-align: middle;'>".$REGISTROS["CALIFICADORA"]."</td>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td style='font-size:1.1rem; vertical-align: middle;'>".$REGISTROS["CALIFICACION"]."</td>\n";
            $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td align='center'>"."<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Actualizar'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' href='#editCalificadora' id='btnActCalificadora'><span class='fa fa-refresh'></span></button></a>"."<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Eliminar'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' href='#inacCalificadora' id='btnDesacCalificadora'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></button></a>"."</td>\n";
        }
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tbody>\n";
        $TABLE .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n";
        fnDesconexion($CONEXION);

        RETURN $TABLE;
    }
```

Por el lado de javascript le doy formato de paginación, exportación, scroll XY de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() //CONTROL PARA DATATABLE CALIFICADORAS
    {
        $('#dtCalificadoras thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i)
        {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () 
            {
                if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) 
                {
                    table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
                }
            });
        });
        var table = $('#dtCalificadoras').DataTable(
        { 
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            buttons: 
            [{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2] },
                text: 'Exporta Calificadoras',
                autoFilter: true,
                sheetName: 'Calificadoras CRM'
            }],

            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true
        });
        table.button(0).nodes().css('background', '#0b91cf');
        table.button(0).nodes().css('border-radius', '2rem 2rem 2rem 2rem');
        table.button(0).nodes().css('color', 'white');
        table.button(0).nodes().css('box-shadow', '0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.18),0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15)');
        $('#dtCalificadoras tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
        {
            var dtCalificadoras = table.row(this).data();
            $("#idActCalificadora").val(dtCalificadoras[0]); //ID CALIFICADRA ACTUALIZAR
            $("#idCalificadora").val(dtCalificadoras[0]); //ID CALIFICADORA DESACTIVAR
            $("#txtCalificadoraEdit").val(dtCalificadoras[1]); //CALIFICADORA ACTUALIZAR
            $("#txtCalificacionEdit").val(dtCalificadoras[2]); //CALIFICACION ACTUALIZAR
            
            document.getElementById("txtCalificadoraDesac").innerHTML=dtCalificadoras[1]; //SECTOR DESACTIVAR
        });
    });
```

Alguien sabe como optimizar la carga del lado del cliente? Gracias, Saludos

Comment: https://datatables.net/faqs/#speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta utilizando la opción que te proporciona datatables que es la de el server side processing.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo proporcionado por ellos
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

El problema se da por que intentas traer todos los resultados de una sola vez y renderizarlos al mismo tiempo. lo que puedes hacer es que te traiga cierta cantidad de datos y al pasar cierta página de tu paginador este cargue otra vez la misma cantidad pero comenzando de donde se quedo la ultima vez.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @SistemasSinZanjas, tiene una infinita biblioteca DataTable. La referencia fue la solución, el tema es que el ejemplo esta Harcodeado, dinámicamente quedo de la siguiente manera, nuevamente gracias y coloco el ejemplo totalmente funcional que sirva de apoyo para todos los demás:

Esqueleto del lado del diseño:

```
<table id='dtCarteraFondos' class='table table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; display: none;'>ID</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Fondo</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Tipo de Inversión</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Emisora</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Serie</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Tipo de Valor</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Calificación de Instrumento de Deuda</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Bursatilidad Instrumento de Renta Variable</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Cantidad de Títulos Operados</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Valor Razonable o Contable Total</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Días por Vencer</th>
            <th style='text-align: center; font-size:1.2rem; vertical-align: middle;'>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Es importante el archivo que contiene la consulta y la base en formato JASON el cual lo llamé: dtcarterafondos.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'Functions.php';

    $CONEXION = fnConexion();
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM VCFONDOS";
    $RESULTADO = mysqli_query($CONEXION,$SQL);

    if(!$RESULTADO)
    {
        die("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        while($DATA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULTADO))
        {
            $ARREGLO["data"][] = $DATA;
        }
        echo json_encode($ARREGLO);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($RESULTADO);
    fnDesconexion($CONEXION);

?>
```

Y para finalizar se invoca la construcción a través de javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() //CONTROL PARA DATATABLE
    {
        listar();
    });
    var listar = function()
    {
        var table = $('#dtCarteraFondos').DataTable(  //ID DE LA TABLA
        {
            "ajax":
            {
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"dtcarterafondos.php" //archivo de conexión
            },
            "columns":
            [
                //{"data":"ID"},
                {"data":"FONDO"},
                {"data":"TIPO_INVERSION"},
                {"data":"EMISORA"},
                {"data":"SERIE"},
                {"data":"TIPO_VALOR"},
                {"data":"CALIFICACION"},
                {"data":"BURSATILIDAD"},
                {"data":"TITULOS_OPERADOS"},
                {"data":"VALOR_RAZONABLE"},
                {"data":"DIAS_XVENCER"},
                {"data":"FECHA"}
            ]
        });
    }
```

Es el ejemplo de la referencia, pero dinámicamente. Saludos